# Airflow task_id not found

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I am trying to set unique id for each of the celery task in airflow. but for some reason it throws me the following error. I even tried with `uuid` module and the same error pops up.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mahesh/anaconda3/bin/airflow", line 37, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/home/mahesh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 76, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mahesh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 547, in run
    task = dag.get_task(task_id=args.task_id)
  File "/home/mahesh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py", line 1263, in get_task
    raise TaskNotFound("Task {task_id} not found".format(task_id=task_id))
airflow.exceptions.TaskNotFound: Task 893370 not found
```

**Following is my DAG**

```
dag_id = 'test'
dag = DAG(dag_id, description='test DAG',
          schedule_interval=None, start_date=datetime(2018, 11, 1), catchup=False)

def my_sleeping_function(**context):
    url = context['url']
    r = requests.head(url)
    return {url : r.status_code}

def fetch_final_result(**context):
    task_instance = context['task_instance']
    ans = []
    print("paypal is ", uuid_list)
    for i in uuid_list:
        data = task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids=i)
        ans.append(data)
    print("uber is ", ans)
    return ans


run_this_bash_last = PythonOperator(
            task_id= 'last',
            python_callable=fetch_final_result,
            # op_kwargs={'url': 'asd'},
            dag=dag,
            provide_context=True)


urls = [website1, website2, website3, website4, website5, website6]

for i in urls:
    index += 1
    ind_id = str(random.randint(1, 100000000000000))
    uuid_list.append(ind_id)
    task_python = PythonOperator(
            # task_id = ind_id,
            task_id = ind_id,
            python_callable=my_sleeping_function,
            op_kwargs={'url': i},
            dag=dag,
            provide_context=True)
task_python.set_downstream(run_this_bash_last)
```

Please suggest how to overcome this

Comment: Why are you randomizing the task_ids? can't the `task_id` simply be the item in `url` list?

Comment: I have tried that but i am getting error like `The key (https://www.swiggy.com/) has to be made of alphanumeric characters, dashes, dots and underscores exclusively`